# MySQL Query Failed: Table 'opencats.module_schema' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, database

I got this error even if I have installed in 'db name'_schema.sql the mysql code :

```
/*Table structure for table `module_schema` */

CREATE TABLE `module_schema` (
`module_schema_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`module_schema_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `module_schema` */

insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (1,'activity',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (2,'attachments',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (3,'calendar',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (4,'candidates',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (5,'careers',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (6,'companies',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (7,'contacts',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (8,'export',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (9,'extension-statistics',1);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (10,'graphs',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (11,'home',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (12,'import',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (13,'install',363);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (14,'joborders',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (15,'lists',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (16,'login',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (17,'queue',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (18,'reports',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (19,'rss',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (20,'settings',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (21,'tests',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (22,'toolbar',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (23,'wizard',0);
insert into `module_schema`(`module_schema_id`,`name`,`version`) values (24,'xml',0);
```

I get this error:

> Failed: Table 'opencats.module_schema' doesn't exist

So what can be the problem?

Comment: As it stands, [your code works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/263307/1). What software are you using? Can you see this table in the `opencats` database?

Comment: Yes, in the table cats_schema.sql

Comment: `cats_schema.sql` sounds like a file, not a table. Connect to your database (e.g. via the console or phpMyAdmin) and examine what tables you have in your database.

Comment: @halfer: Thank you for your comments. The mysql database has crashed. I used the wrong php version (it had to be a version of php between 5.5 and 5.6.27. So nI have now sorted the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: OK, great. It looks like you need to upgrade PHP at some point - can you upgrade to 7.x? 5.5 is out of support already, and 5.6 will go soon.

Comment: Voting to close, from the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: But note that the latest release of OpenCats is not compatible with php 7.x. So for now I will stick to the earlier version.

Comment: That may be a security risk.